# what does !Array.<string>= mean in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Been reading the AngularJS documentation and found some param type

```
!Array.<string>=
```

What does this mean? any answer would clear things up.

Comment: can you point to the link for context?

Comment: You can see it in the [code](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js) - That is an type indicator for the parameter saying it is expecting an array of string values as the said parameter

Comment: @Gary

[Angular Module](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/docs/api/ng/function/angular.module)

Comment: @ArunPJohny Well why the !Array.<string>? is '!' an inverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operators are from Google Closure's [Type Expressions](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#types).

- `!` identifies the type as "*Non-nullable*."
- `<...>` identifies the type(s) of an object/collection's contents.
- `=` identifies the parameter as "*Optional*."

So, in the case of [`angular.module()`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/docs/api/ng/function/angular.module):

- No argument has to be given for `requires`.
- When it is given, it cannot be `null` and must be an `Array` containing only string values.

```
angular.module('Foo');               // valid arguments
angular.module('Foo', null);         // not valid
angular.module('Foo', ['Bar']);      // valid
angular.module('Foo', [false]);      // not valid
angular.module('Foo', function(){}); // valid
```

Comment: but what about the Array.<string> @JonathanLonowski?

is the <string> the type??

Comment: The `<...>` represents the type of the contents/elements/etc., so `Array<string>` is an "*array of strings*."